# Hyperlinks with ios recipe on kivy-ios

Tags: ios, kivy

I'm trying to make a hyperlink that launches safari when clicked. I gather that this involves using iOS's native API, however I noticed in the kivy-ios package, there's a recipe called "ios" that seems to have this function built in.

I've not been able to google this successfully, maybe because searches for "kivy ios package" bring up the kivy-ios package which isn't what I'm looking for.

How can I use this and is there any documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The source of the `ios` module is in the `recipes/ios/src` folder. It doesn't contain much so you can probably get what you need by just reading it.

You probably want the `open_url` function, which I think you can import as `from ios.ios import open_url`.

Comment: That'd be great, but how do I go about making this module available to import? Right now I get "no such module". I've built it with `toolchain.py build ios` and updated my xcode project with `toolchain.py update /path/to/dir`

Comment: I'm not familiar with kivy-ios' command line, but you want to add `ios` to the included requirements (alongside kivy, sdl2 etc.)